# How to resolve String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. - Client Object Model Sharepoint on Premise

Tags: csv, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-clientobject

I have written a script that imports data into a from a specified CSV file to a list in a specified SharePoint 2013 site (on premise). However, when I come to run the script, I get these two errors:
[image]

I understand why I am getting these errors. It is because the column in the CSV file which holds Date fields contains blanks. I would put these blanks to a date however, there is another column in SharePoint where if it's value is "1" that column **MUST NOT** contain a date.

What can I add to my script to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Sam D Harris

Comment: First, you should share your code with us.

Comment: And the string that you are converting. Maybe it's not a datetime as is.

Comment: Code like jisaak says and some of the sample data to be sure what we are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sam I am sharing the code for adding date data from CSV to sharepoint list using powershell.

In your foreach loop which reads every line of imported CSV.

```
    [DateTime]$loggedOnDate = New-Object System.DateTime;

    $newItem = $list.items.add();

    if([DateTime]::TryParse($item."Logged On", [ref]$loggedOnDate)){            
       $newitem["LoggedOn"] = $loggedOnDate;            
    }

    $newitem.update();
```

Where :- $item."Logged On" -  "Logged On" is column name in CSV file. and $newitem["LoggedOn"] is column name in splist.

Now lets start anwering your query with assumption that CSV has two columns

- 'Active' - values [0 or 1]
- Logged On - Date column

Powershell code to add csv data in sharepoint would be.

```
$newItem = $list.items.add();

 IF(($item.Active -ne 1)
 {
       [DateTime]$loggedOnDate = New-Object System.DateTime;

    if([DateTime]::TryParse($item."Logged On", [ref]$loggedOnDate)){            
               $newitem["LoggedOn"] = $loggedOnDate;            
        }
}

$newitem.update();
```

Make sure default value for Date column in sharepoint list should be blank.